# I am trying to create a steam tax calculator, but it is failing horribly

Tags: python-3.x

Whatever i try, it always comes up with this error:

```
line 8, in <module>
    print(Bprice * Tax)
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Code:

```
print ("Steam market calculator")

Tax = 0.8789

buysell = input("Are you buying or selling an item? (buy/sell)")
if buysell == ("buy"):
   Bprice = input("What is the buyprice?")
   print(Bprice * Tax)
```

It never works. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `input` in python it will return a string. You try to multiply that string to a float.

try

```
Bprice = float(input("What is the buyprice?"))
```

Also, dont use capitalized variables, it's not good practice

Answer (score 0):

`Bprice` is a String, not a number. You need to convert it to a number first:

```
print(float(Bprice) * Tax)
#      ^ float() converts it to a decimal number
```

Be careful though, as if Bprice isn't convertible to a number, you'll get an error.

Comment: If I enter, `Bprice = input("What is the buyprice?")` in Python and respond with a number, Python seems to handle `Bprice` as a number (I can do `print(Bprice * Tax)` afterwards without conversion).

Comment: @lurker What was the value of `Bprice` and `Tax`.

Comment: `Bprice = 3.50` (I typed `3.50` at the `input` prompt) and `Tax = 0.8789`. It seemed to work just fine without the conversion. Are you seeing an error when you try it without conversion?

Comment: @lurker Were you using Python 2?

Comment: Ah.... yes, I am using Python 2.7.12. So the behavior is different in Python 3.x...

Comment: Ya. The `input` was doing an implicit `eval` which (dangerously) handled the conversion for you.